Probably lost 500Gb of data - how to recover the data?
Yeah I know I fucked up. Just asking if there is a slight chance of recovering data.
I have an external SSD for backup, 1TB. Because some time ago I had some windows stuff, it had half ntfs and half exfat.
The exfat was full, so I decided to get rid of the windows partition. I wanted, ideally, to finally get at a single ext4 partition of the whole disk.
I fired up gparted, first deleted the windows partition and then tried to make the data partition bigger. Somehow that was not working, it was moving the whole partition,but not resizing it. I assume exfat doesn't support that.
Then I fatally saw the "Format to" command. I had a momentary loss of awareness, I guess. For some reason I concluded this to mean it would convert the data partition to ext4.
So I hit apply.
It took me a couple of seconds to realize what was going on...I hit cancel but I guess the damage is complete nonetheless.
Is there any chance that I can recover the data?
Currently the partition doesn't even mount, surely because I interrupted the operations after starting.

why don't you ask how to recover the data? ... your only question has a yes answer, which is not very useful

Edited the title

Not sure how much damage has already been done by Format. But see if the following works
First of all burn the latest SystemResuceCD into a Flash/USB drive and boot it.
Connect your external drive into Computer and see what is the output of the two commands in terminal lsblk -T -f -p and blkid. It should show the partitions on the external disk. Check whether it is showing as NTFS or exFAT or something else. Then try to mount the partition, say /dev/sdc1 which was originally NTFS, as NTFS and see if you can recover from that. This document should help you.
If this does not work, i.e. the partition is not listed as NTFS or is not visible then you will have to use another utility in the SystemRescueCD called as testdisk. There is a decent documentation in the form of PDF and other sources. Go through it and see if you can recover the data.
Now since you have started the format, one way to recover data is to rebuild the NTFS partition table . In the PDF document listed above there is a section called as RECOVERING DELETED PARTITION USING TESTDISK which covers this. That should be your final option while using testdisk. Go through the documents it will give you more details.
The other option is to use dd command. However please do note that if the partition is listed as exFAT then this might not be advisable. As the partition table of NTFS has been lost. And you need to rebuild the NTFS partition table first.
One caution these steps will involve you to mount the partition which was NTFS previously. Please make sure that you always mount it as ready-only, i.e. "ro". Only when you try to rebuild the NTFS partition table should you mount it as "rw". So that should be your last option.
There are commercial tools that are available that are not part of the SystemResuceCD. For example EaseUS or DiskPart or DiskDrill, etc.
Finally if SystemRescueCD does not work then try HIRENS Boot CD. You can look at this answer from Super User forum which has more details.

Thank you for this extensive offer of help. I will go through it one by one and see if something works!

Remember to keep a backup. I cannot assure you that the steps outlined above will work. And to reiterate rebuilding your NTFS partition table should be your last option, exhaust everything else.

Windows tools are typically best for Microsoft formats like NTFS & exFAT. Your exFAT is not as easily recoverable as it is not journaled and only uses a single file allocation table and free space map. I might try testdisk to see if it can see old partition table structure first.
